# ajax form submission with jquery validations

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I'm trying to submit my contact form using AJAX with jQuery validation. I think there are errors in passing form data. The validation works properly but something is wrong with the AJAX that I'm unable to figure it out. Please review my code below and help me to sort out it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test-form').validate({
        rules: {
            name:{
                required: true,
            },
            org: {
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email:true,
                maxlength: 50,
            },
            phone:{
                number:true
            },
            message:{
                required: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required:"Enter Your Name",
            },
            org: {
                required:"Enter Your Organisation",
            },
            email: {
                required: "Enter Your Email Address",
                email: "Enter correct email format",
            },
            phone:{
                number : "Phone number must contain digits only",
            },
            message:{
                required: "Enter Your Message",
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form, e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('three');

            var This = $(this);
            var action = $(This).attr('action');
            var data_value = unescape($(This).serialize());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: data_value,
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#ajax_contact_msg').html(response);
                }            
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Check your console for errors. What is the value of `data_value` that you send? Also note there's no need to put `This` in a jQuery object - it already is one

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `submitHandler` event use `.valid()` function of jquery validate. which allow ajax call only when all the form fields meet validations.

Please check below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test-form').validate({

    rules: {
      name:{
        required: true,
      },

      org:{
        required: true,
      },

      email:{
        required: true,
        email:true,
        maxlength: 50,

      },
      phone:{
        number:true
      },
      message:{
        required: true,
      }


    },
    messages: {
      name: {
        required:"Enter Your Name",
      },

      org: {
        required:"Enter Your Organisation",
      },

      email: {
        required: "Enter Your Email Address",
        email: "Enter correct email format",
      },
      phone:{

        number : "Phone number must contain digits only",
      },
      message:{
        required: "Enter Your Message",
      }

    }
  });
});

if($('#test-form').valid()){
  alert('three');

  var This = $(this);

  var action = $(This).attr('action');
  var data_value = unescape($(This).serialize());
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:action,
    data: data_value,

    success: function(response) {
      $('#ajax_contact_msg').html(response);
    }            
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This will mean that the standard form submission still occurs so the AJAX request will not complete properly. Using the `submitHandler` is the correct way to do this.